# Attributes are empty during unit test of a taglib in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, taglib

I am trying to test my code in taglib (grails 2.0.1):

```java
class ATagLib {
    static namespace = "s"
    def person = {attrs, body -> out << attrs.person;}
}

@TestFor(ATagLib)
class ATagLibTests {
   @Test
   void test() {
       String p = 'Joe'
       // None of these work for me.
       assert applyTemplate('<s:person person="${p}"/>') == 'Joe'
       assert applyTemplate('<s:person/>', [person:p]) == 'Joe'
   }
}
```

The test always fails, because attrs.person is null. How do I properly set attributes?

Answer (score 2):

This will work :

```
String p = 'Joe'
assert applyTemplate('<s:person person="${person}"/>', [person:p]) == 'Joe'
assertOutputEquals('Joe is cool !', '<s:person person="${person}"/>', [person:p], { it.toString() + " is cool !" } )
```

It calls the first signature of applyTemplate, which is :

```
String applyTemplate(String contents, Map model = [:])
```

[image]

Comment: That's weird. I tested it with no problem in my environment... How do you launch your tests ? From the command-line ? Interactive console ? STS ?

Comment: Well... I used STS and the command-line and both worked fine. How did you launch your tests in STS (which command did you type) ? Can you give us the directory structure of your app with the paths to the taglib and the test case ?

Comment: This is how I tested it:
grails create-app ut; cd ut; grails create-tag-lib ATagLib; I added code as it was shown in my question, and then I used grails test-app unit:. The test fails, because applyTemplate returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you are using single quotes for your template text? Only GStrings can use the $ notation for inserting variables. Single quotes make it a regular Java String which won't substitute your value in.

Try this:

```
assert applyTemplate("<s:person person=\"${p}\"/>") == "Joe"
```

Comment: Thanks David, but it did not work. I also tried to switch single/double quotes around or use triple quotes. Neither helped.

Comment: @AlexanderShyrokov What do you see if you print `attrs` out from within the tag library.